# JavaScript function return not staying in browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a very simple HTML site for my co-workers to use for calculating cellular phone pricing based on a formula. I have a form with user inputs to declare the full price of the phone, amount of down payment, etc. Basically everything seems to be working, however the returned answer from my formula in my JavaScript function only displays on the screen for a fraction of a second and the JavaScript seems to reload. Have I unintentionally caused a loop?

I am very new to JavaScript please let me know if I am leaving out any pertinent information to helping to solve this issue. I will include my code below.

```
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id ="formula">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Finance Formula</legend>
                <div id="label">
                    <label for="fullPrice">Full Price:</label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label for="downPay">Down Payment:</label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label for="discount">Discount:</label>
                </div>

                <div id="input">
                    <input type="text" id="fullPrice" name="fullPrice" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" id="downPay" name="downPay" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" />
                </div>  

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="financed();"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="resultsBox">    
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function financed(){
    var fullPrice = document.getElementById('fullPrice').value;
    var downPay = document.getElementById('downPay').value;
    var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;

    console.log("The Total Amount Paid for Phone is:" +(((parseInt(fullPrice) - parseInt(downPay)) / 24) - parseInt(discount)) * 24); 
};

</script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I have also tried this script instead which is what I found when researching online.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function financed(){
    var fullPrice = document.getElementById('fullPrice').value;
    var downPay = document.getElementById('downPay').value;
    var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (((parseInt(fullPrice) - parseInt(downPay)) / 24) - parseInt(discount)) * 24;
};

</script>
```

Basically the end result I am looking for is the answer for the equation within the function to "print" onto the browser and stay there.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements have default behaviors when they're used-- forms, for instance, will refresh the page on submit.  Fortunately, there is a preventDefault method that will stop this behavior.  You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

You just need to add an event listener to your submit tag, like this:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your submit input reloads the page by default. Try removing the onClick from submit and calling this instead:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // preventing the default submit action
    financed();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally form submit will navigate to the action attribute url, if there is no action attribute, navigate to same page. if you want to avoid this default behaviour you have to modify the tag or submit button like mentioned below.

```
<form id ="formula" action="javascript:void(0)">
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="clickme" onclick="financed();"/>
```